# Can you put a bottle of whiskey in the oven

Tags: oven, alcohol, kitchen-safety

I was in the mood to give someone a bottle of whiskey, but to customize it, I wanted to decorate it with polymer clay. But to set polymer clay, you have to put it in the oven and so therefore I would have to put it on the bottle of alcohol and then put in the oven.

My question is, is it safe to keep the bottle unopened with alcohol inside or should I just pour out the alcohol and reseal it with wax?

Comment: What temperature do you need to bake the clay at, and for how long?

Comment: Also, are you assuming that the clay will stick to glass? If you haven't tried it before I would not expect that to work. A better solution is probably to make your decorations, bake them without the bottle, then stick them on with glue.

Comment: Interesting question -- may want to migrate to Arts & Crafts if it's not on topic here.

Comment: You may want to test this on a cheap bottle first.

Comment: @Mast and a cheap oven, a cheap kitchen, cheap hands and cheap eyes.

Comment: The recipient needs to know it's been decanted so they don't put it on a shelf for a year and then try to drink it.

Comment: @Mazura: What would happen otherwise?

Comment: "After opening, it should be consumed within 6–8 months for peak taste, according to industry experts."

Comment: I would just make the decorations and then hot glue them to the bottle or make a bottle cosy and put the decorations on that.

Comment: In addition to the safety concerns, wouldn't heating the whiskey also ruin, or at least alter, its taste?

Comment: @dbmag9 110-130 C (230-266 F). Fimo needs 110 C for 30 min; I would think it might just work, partly because of the heat inertia of the fluid.

Comment: If you want to get a look at just **how bad** this can go, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XjwVYkwB_w The title of this TV show was literally "don't try this at home", and they show the effects of cooking a champagner bottle in a microwave oven. "Don't try this at home" is an excellent advice when it comes to sealed liquid containers inside heating devices. Just imagine that poor microwave was your own oven!

Comment: Do not do this ever.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: ok, but that has almost nothing to do with the alcohol content of champagne, just the fact that it's heavily pressurized with CO2, 4-6 atmospheres / 60-90 psi. You could get a similar explosion effect from a bottle of soda water. Also, the champagne bottle cork wrapper has metal, which will heat.

Comment: @smci Sorry, but you entirely failed to see the point: The heated water is the problem. Not the alcohol, not the CO2, just plain water. These two guys were heating water that was trapped inside a comparatively robust glass bottle *way* beyond 100°C, kept liquid only by the quickly rising pressure (way beyond 10bar, I'd guess) inside the bottle. At one point, the bottle simply failed to retain the pressure, and the entire water instantly turned into steam, deciding that there was not enough room inside the microwave oven either. I only talked about *heating a sealed liquid container* on purpose

Comment: @cmaster Well, [at 110C or 120C water needs only 2 bar or so to stay fluid](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-vapor-saturation-pressure-d_599.html), that is, 1 bar over-pressure, which most bottles will likely sustain. Chances are that the fluid will not have heated up all the way anyway in 30 minutes. On the other hand it's 30% alcohol which lowers the boiling point and probably increases the pressure at 110C, so the details are murky; but all in all I'd bet a tenner that the bottle holds.

Comment: @dbmag9 If getting it to stick to glass is an issue, roughening the glass may help.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, if the temperature is only slightly above boiling point, it *may* go well. But I certainly wouldn't try it. Even if the force of the explosion would be much more limited than in the microwaved champagne case, those 30% alcohol would flash boil just the same and probably come into contact with the hot heating elements of the oven, producing a *fiery* explosion. All it takes for a fire ball to form, is that the cap on the bottle fails.

Answer (score 53):

In general, you wouldn't want to put a sealed glass bottle filled with any liquid in your oven.

If you want to try and are still working on it, remove the cap, empty the alcohol into another container, bake the bottle and cap covered in clay separately leaving room to screw the cap on.

Let the bottle cool completely, then add the alcohol back in.

It's imperative that you let the bottle cool to room temperature, the shock of the oven hot bottle having liquid poured into it would probably shatter it.

In my opinion, baking a sealed, full bottle, is just asking for either a dangerous accident or a big mess.

Comment: To me, this is only opinion that, in part, repeats what the poster already stated.

Comment: It's best to be descriptive when you're answering a question.

Comment: Additionally, putting the open bottle with whiskey in it in the oven will result in you not having whiskey afterwards (you’ll have _something_, but it won’t be whiskey, and I wouldn’t want to drink it after it had been in an oven with setting polymer clay).

Comment: A large container of liquid is going to be a thermal sink, throwing off the curing times for your clay.  Also, you’d want to make sure you’re using a clay that doesn’t shrink as it cures or it’ll peel itself off.  You might try wrapping another (empty) bottle in parchment, making and curing your design, and then gluing it onto the full bottle

Comment: Let's get down to brass tacks: "baking a sealed, full bottle, is just asking"... **TO EXPLODE**.

Comment: Note that you may well also need to turn the oven off and let it cool completely before you open the door at all.  It depends on how high the curing temperature is, but a cold draft from opening the door could potentially induce enough thermal shock to shatter the bottle.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You may want to add this video link to your answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XjwVYkwB_w It shows the effect of cooking a bottle of champagne in a microwave oven. The explosion totally blows the oven to pieces...

Comment: It's probably worth noting that unless it's Pyrex or some other sort of glass meant for cooking, it's generally a bad idea to put glass in the oven.  Polymer clay cooking temps are pretty low but the brittleness of the non-shatterproof glass used in whiskey bottles heated and then add internal pressure?  Not likely to end well.  I once left a glass growler bottle of fermenting cider in the fridge and it exploded; turning the maple syrup bottle (not unlike a whiskey bottle in design) next to it into a bazillion shards of razor-sharp fragments.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 24):

#### Use different modelling clay

Two-part putties such as Milliput are just as well designed for fine model-making, and set in air at room temperature.

If you start with a white putty then you can mix it with acrylic paint to colour it.  It'll be weaker but this probably isn't an issue. It'll also set faster with the water in the acrylic paint though, so only mix up a small quantity at a time. Or just use plain white and paint it.

Answer (score 22):

I don't know how hot or how long your polymer clay bakes for, so you might get away with it, but in general I wouldn't risk putting a sealed container in the oven, whatever the contents.

The primary risk isn't alcohol igniting, but vapour forming in the bottle under pressure can break the bottle or more likely the cap. If the alcohol was going to ignite, it would have to get out of the bottle and mix with air anyway. Loosening the lid would relieve the pressure, but there is some chance of hot alcohol fumes igniting if there's an ignition source. This probably wouldn't be catastrophic. The large thermal mass of the contents works in your favour, but the long baking time means the drink can get quite hot.

You may also scorch the label or cap, spoiling the existing print. At the fairly low temperatures used for most polymer clay this isn't too likely,

Comment: You also won’t have whiskey afterwards if it’s open, because the alcohol and most of the aromatics that make it whiskey will evaporate pretty quickly even at low temperatures.

Comment: Quite a bit of the alcohol would go if fully open, and a fair bit of water too, but it would ruin decent whisky. If just open enough to vent the pressure, the effect would be much less (@Austin)

Comment: "Relieving the pressure" almost certainly means losing a fair bit of alcohol.

Comment: @chepner, alcohol doesn't evaporate that much faster than the water, and will take some time to heat up. So it will get a little weaker, but reduce in volume a fair bit. I was trying to stick to the safety aspect the question concentrated on,but I don't think it would be good for the whisky either

Comment: Glass is not a good thermal insulator; if the inside stays below 100 C (the point at which vapor pressure of the water will rise dramatically), will that heat sink keep the clay from getting hot enough to set?  [a comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113348/alcohol-safety-can-you-put-a-bottle-of-whiskey-in-the-oven#comment180828_113348) indicates an *oven* temp of 110-130 C (230-266 F) for 30 min.  With normal pottery, you'd expect the material to get close to that hot by the end, within maybe 10 or 20 degrees?

Comment: @PeterCordes glass isn't a great conductor of heat either. It's annoyingly in between. But rather then relying too heavily on the insulating properties of glass, I'm thinking of the contents taking time to heat up - of course the heat has to pass through the glass, but if you put half a litre of cold water (spirits will evaporate faster, but not by too much) in a fairly thick walled glass container, the rise won't be too bad. At least it won't boil, though the vapour pressure will rise. I'd chill it only that would increase the thermal stress on the glass

Comment: Right, that was kind of my point: the inside liquid is pulling heat away from the outsides.  But you *need* the outside to get hot to actually cure / set / bake the clay.  If the outside doesn't get hot like it's supposed to, it won't fully set.  (Or you'd have to leave it in longer, and the insides would eventually get hot enough to be a problem..)

Comment: @Peter the clay will heat much faster than the contents. Glass isn't that good a conductor. I'd go as hot as the clay allows, for the shortest time, testing on something similar but scrap first.

Comment: Hotter/shorter is a good idea.  Yeah, test that with a used bottle, maybe filled with an equal amount of water and the lid on tight.

Answer (score 8):

It might cause an explosion and a house fire. A sealed bottle would explode without a doubt. The heat differential caused by different thicknesses of clay would stress the glass. The combination of heated alcohol vapour and the heating elements of the oven would probably blow the door off your oven and set your kitchen on fire.

If you decide to go ahead, make sure you video it and leave the room. It would make a spectacular video on social media!

Comment: Indeed. While not quite Darwin Award material, the OP's idea is certainly an exciting one.

Answer (score 3):

### You're making a pressure cooker.

That's a very bad idea.  The pressure *will* escape once it builds high enough.  Either will happen:

1. the glass and clay hold together, and the cap blows off, spraying flammable liquid into the hot oven, or
2. the glass and clay shatter, not only spraying flammable liquid into the hot oven but also lots of sharp, high-speed fragments everywhere.

In either case, there will be a fire in the oven, and the glass will probably break.

### Bottom line: it's a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is a sweet idea for a gift.  But heating closed things makes them blow up.  Here is how you can get where you want to be safely.

1. Make a sleeve the size of your bottle.  Or use an open empty bottle the same size.
2. Decorate sleeve with polymer clay.  Or decorate empty bottle with circumferential clay decor.
3. Put decorated sleeve onto gift bottle with a little glue to hold in place.  Or slide clay off of empty bottle (if you put it in the freezer bottle will shrink and this should not be hard) and glue pieces onto gift bottle.  Curve will be correct.